# Working with multiple Classes. Program won't launch

Tags: java, class, variables, public

I've been working on a rather large program, and thought it was time to split up my classes. 1 .java file for the GUI code, and 1 .java file for the mechanics behind the functions the GUI presents. But here's my issue, I've created an instance of each class inside each other, and the program then refuses to launch, so I'm clearly doing something wrong. In my `RPG` class I have the following line of code:

```
public Mechanics mechanics = new Mechanics();
```

And for my `Mechanics` class, I have this code:

```
public RPG rpg = new RPG();
```

The reason why I'm doing this WAS to try this:
A lot of my variables are in the `RPG` class, and I want to be able to call them from my `rpg` and manipulate them, then send them back to `RPG` Here is the code I used to test this function (from my `Mechanics` class):

```
class Mechanics{
public RPG rpg = new RPG();
  public Mechanics(){
  }
  public void helloWorld(){
    System.out.println("Hello World!");
    System.out.println("Health before:"+rpg.Health);
    rpg.Health = rpg.Health - 5;
    System.out.println("Health after:"+rpg.Health);
  }
 }
```

Yes, `Health` is a public `int` in my `RPG` class.

And in my `RPG` class, this is the code I am using to test my `Mechanics` class:

```
mechanics.helloWorld();
```

Here's my problem: The code compiles, but then when I try to run it, I get this error:

```
 at Mechanics.<init>(Mechanics.java:15)
 at RPG.<init>(RPG.java:127)
```

[image]
Here's my question. Am I even doing this right? Whats wrong with my code that's making my program not want to run?

**ADDED:** I have tried called my other classes as a `private` as well, and the program will compile, and still refuses to launch, and feeds me the same error

Line 15 of `Mechanics`:

```
public RPG rpg = new RPG();
```

line 127 of `RPG`:

```
public Mechanics mechanics = new Mechanics();
```

Comment: Can you show us the full stack trace? You don't seem to have included the name of the exception.

Comment: That's all the console feeds me, I'll add an image to help you guys. I've even scrolled to the top of the console and this is all it says

Comment: if the name of exception is missed then the error must be a corrupted java/eclipse file. Maybe jvm is bugged.

Comment: Ah thats a stack overflow if ever I saw one!

Comment: Does that look like an infinite recursion?

Comment: You could also show us what's at Line 15 in Mechanics.java and what's on line 127 at RPG.java.

Comment: What's inside the constructor of RPG?

Comment: Yea, we need line 15 of mechanics.

Comment: Also, why would you downvote me? I provided as much as I could gather involving my issue, which is less then 50 lines of code. I'm sorry you're confused.

Comment: I think your constraints are looped. Dependencies(objects) are created again and again due to this.

Comment: @user2388169 Well, you might have been downvoted because your original question was misleading (obscuring the stack overflow by only citing the error message once), and not providing all the relevant code (how the objects whose methods you're calling are being created). Seems harsh since the problems are fixable, but it happens. (Hence the "might have", as in the -1 isn't mine.) There's usually very little point in complaining about downvotes, the downvoters most likely moved on if they didn't add a comment, and it just disrupts the people who stuck around with your question.

Comment: I've updated my question with the lines in the console

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Line 15 of `Mechanics` might be more like:

```
public RPG rpg = new RPG(this); // must be in constructor or non static method
```

In RPG:

```
public Mechanics mechanics;
```

in the constructor:

```
this.mechanics = mechanics;
```

Comment: Would I be able to call `RPG rpg = new RPG();` in any amount of new constructors or methods?

Comment: This actually fixed my issue and aloud my program to run. I can now call variables from either class, if needed, and used them as needed.

Comment: Glad you got it sorted. :)

Comment: @user2388169 Well, depends. Do you need to have multiple `RPG` objects? If not, then just create one and wire it up once and for all. If so, then do you need each of them to have its own copy of the `Mechanics` object? If you can share the `Mechanics` object, do so, by having some sort of *factory* create the `RPG` objects instead of calling the constructor directly, and pass the shared copy into the constructor. If you can't share the `Mechanics`, it's possible for one object to create the other, but then you should decide which one is the "owner" and handles creating its dependencies.

Comment: @user2388169 Generally, using object factories and such seems like overkill and "enterprisey", but the advantage is that it gives you a place to answer design questions like "how many of X may exist?", and "which X should be connected to which Y?", and keep these answers outside of the implementation of `X` and `Y` which should ideally only do what their purpose is, and not worry about the relationship between one another except for the facts that such a relationship exists and "somebody else" takes care of it.

Answer (score 5):

It's because you instantiating a new `Mechanics` class inside of the `RPG` class. Then instantiating a new `RPG` class inside the `Mechanics` class.

The result is an infinite loop of instantiation.

For your specific example, I personally think the best way to fix the issue would be to pass the RPG instance directly into the hello world method.

```
class Mechanics {
    public void helloWorld(RPG rpg) {
        ...
    }
}
```

And then in your RPG class would look something like:

```
class RPG {
    // passing a mechanics object in via the constructor would be better than hard-coding it here
    public Mechanics mechanics = new Mechanics();

    public int Health = 100;
    ...

    public void someMethod() {
        mechanics.helloWorld(this); // pass in the rpg instance
    }
}
```

Comment: And a tip for him to fix it? Dependency injection, perhaps?

Comment: Is there a way around this? I need both files to be able to communicate with each other. This why I can cut down of the amount of lines in ONE source files, and stay organized.

Comment: @user2388169 Generally what you do is that you create as many of the "important" objects up front, **before** they actually do anything. Then pass them around to one another as constructor parameters or by setting properties. And only then do you start the program itself. In general, it's considered a bad practice for an object to create "collaborators" (other objects it needs to hold on to for a long time) itself.

Comment: @user2388169 the simplest way for you to go forward, use setters instead of `new` for your RPG and Mechanics member variables. Then "wire it up" from the outside.

Comment: @vikingsteve or pass references in the constructor, otherise you risk creating "half objects" that if used without calling specific methods will lead to null pointer excptions

Comment: @RichardTingle yes, for sure, and if the circular dependency can be avoided completely that would be even better.

Answer (score 2):

You are producing an infinite loop when initializing an instance of either RPG or Mechanics. Object-oriented programming means seperation of concerns and low coupling. Change your class dependencies so that only one of them needs the other.

Comment: Is there no way that I can have both classes talk to each other? I would really like the make 1 `class` for GUI, and 1 `class` for the Mechanics of the program. But there are `JLabels` `JButtons` and `JTextAreas` I need to update from the GUI `Class`

Comment: @user2388169, you might want to use event handling model when core generates and sends events to the gui and vice versa.

Comment: So I could make my GUI, and then just call my `Mechanics` class, and just add results to events and everything? That would be a lot easier?

Comment: You should spend some time to read about [programming patterns](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_design_pattern). Also interesting: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/382623/what-are-your-3-most-important-programming-patterns-and-why

Answer (score 1):

"I've created an instance of each class inside each other"

This is your problem, the net results is this:

Class A is constructed, it has a class B within it, it creates a new Class B 
Class B is constructed, it has a class A within it, it creates a new Class A 
Class A is constructed, it has a class B within it, it creates a new Class B 
Class B is constructed, it has a class A within it, it creates a new Class A 
Class A is constructed, it has a class B within it, it creates a new Class B 
Class B is constructed, it has a class A within it, it creates a new Class A

etc etc forever, getting deeper and deeper until your program crashes.

Theres nothing (horribly) wrong with `class A` having a *reference* to `class B` and `class B` having a *reference* to `class A` (although it may not be ideal), but there is something horribly wrong with `class A` encapsulating `class B` and `class B` encapsulating `class A`. In the case that both have references to each other then a reference to one or both would be passed into one or both's constructor, thereby not using the `new` keyword (avoid even this if possible though).

An example of this I often (guiltily) use is the following:

```
public class OwnerClass {
    SubordinateClass subOrdinate;

    public OwnerClass(){
        subOrdinate=new SubordinateClass(this);
    }

}

public class SubordinateClass {
    OwnerClass owner;

    public SubordinateClass(OwnerClass owner){
        this.owner=owner;
    }
}
```

Disclaimer: I'm not presenting this as good practice, *but* assuming that class A must talk to class B and vice versa then this achieves that

Comment: the computer does not need to crash ;)